# Django Duplication objects

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement a comment feature inside my whiteboard.The feature allows Students to comment on each other pictures.

I have an app where students can create virtual whiteboard and post pictures relating to homework inside the whiteboards.

When the user clicks to view the comment under a specific picture . The comment does appear on that specific picture but the same comment appears on all the picture which it isn't suppose too.

I'm been trying figure out a way to implement a comment feature and this is the only idea I though of.
How could I fix this duplication problem because I"m been trying to figure out a way to associate the picture with the comments.

Take a look at the whiteboard >

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/90792660.jpg/

My whiteboard.html

```
 {% if picture %}
 <ul>
    {% for pet in picture %}


        {% if pet.image %}

    <a href ="{% url world:LikePicture pet.id %}"><br>
        <img src= "{{ pet.image.url }}" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
 <br>
    </a>
 </li>
        {% endif %}

 <br>
 <a href="{% url world:CommentCreator pet.id %}">View Comment</a><br/>
      {% for c in comment %}
           <br>{{ c.body }}</li>
           <br>{{ c.created}}</li>
           <br>{{ c.user}}</li>
 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
                </ul>
 {% endif %}
```

My views.py

```
 def Boat(request ,animal_id):
         if not request.user.is_authenticated():
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

    picture = Picture.objects.filter(whiteboard=animal_id)

    return render(request,'whiteboard.html',{'picture':picture})

 def CommentCreator(request,picture_id):
     p = Picture.objects.get(pk=picture_id)
     comment = Comment.objects.filter(picture=p)
     Whiteboard = WhiteBoard.objects.get(whiteboard=p)
     the_id = board.id
     picture = Picture.objects.filter(whiteboard=the_id)

     return render(request,'whiteboard.html',{'picture':picture,'comment':comment})
```

My models.py

```
 class WhiteBoard(models.Model):

     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     picture = models.OneToOneField('Picture',related_name='picture',blank=True,null=True)
     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name

 class Picture(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     Whiteboard = models.ForeignKey(WhiteBoard,blank=False,null=False,related_name='board')
     image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True)
     description = models.TextField()
     is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.description
 class Comment(models.Model):
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     body = models.TextField()
     picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url world:CommentCreator pet.id %}">View Comment</a><br/>

{% for c in comment %}
    {% ifequal c.picture.id pet.id %}
        <br>{{ c.body }}</li>
        <br>{{ c.created}}</li>
        <br>{{ c.user}}</li>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It work perfectly ,thank you. If I want to close off the comment . LIke click it again to hide . How would I do it?

Comment: you better apply jscript on that

Comment: it's better if you ask another question for that :)